# I am making a bot in discord.py and i used the client.remove_command to remove help cmd which is made by default, but it doesnt work. Code below:

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
client.remove_command('help')

@client.command()
async def help(ctx):
  embed=discord.Embed(color=0x3e4ec1)
  embed.add_field(name="Admin", value="Ban, Unban, Kick, Purge", inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name="Levels", value="rank, rewardlevels, removelevels", inline=False) 
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

As u see i have used client.remove_command('help)
but when i run the command it still shows me the default help dialogue.

[image]

so it shows me this.

Comment: Do you mind sending a screenshot of what happens when you run the help command?

Comment: What is `client`'s value? What did you set to `client`? That could be a clue.

Comment: Yes i can share the screenshot @Makonede.

Comment: See Mark's comment. How did you define `client`? Or could you mind just sharing more of your code in general?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the help command when initializing your client object.

```
client = commands.Bot(
command_prefix="!",
help_command=None)
```

From there you can make your own help command.

```
@client.command()
async def help(ctx):
    #put your embed/command descriptions or whatever you want here
    await ctx.channel.send("This is a help command.")
```